# How to release an Image from an ImageView when this ImageView is over scrolled

Tags: android

I have an linear layout that store a lot of imageViews. And ImageViews are added when the linear layout is scroll down.
But when I have alot of images, it make OutOfMemory (OOM) exception.
I want to release all images that are out of the screen. 
How can I do that.

thanks all,

p/s sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

If you can use ListView/Gallery/GridView with Adapter, then android will re-use the view for ListView items, the gc thread will have a chance to swap out the images

Another thing you can try is to extend ImageView and override the onDetachedFromWindow method, this method will be invoked when the view detach from the window. In this method, you may get a chance to release the images.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but
I have to use linear layout to add image view for some reasons.
I have override OnDetachFromWindow, and nothing happen when a image view is hidden.
Can you give me more advise
Thanks